# Rails check if object with foreign key constraint can be deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship

Department, Course, Student classes.

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :department
 has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :course
end
```

Department and course have dependent delete foreign_key constraint.
When a department is deleted, all its courses have to be deleted. But if a course has a student assigned to it, the course cannot be deleted. Meaning, the department in turn cannot be deleted.

Now, I need to find if a department can be deleted, in order to display the delete link in the index page. Is there a way I can find that out without querying through all courses, to check if they have students assigned? The problem is, I have to display hundreds of departments. And for showing each delete link, I need to query a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The most performance-friendly way to handle this situation would probably be to just show the delete key all the time and add a before_destroy ActiveRecord Callback which could check that the department can be destroyed.

Keep in mind that if you really want to only show the delete link for those that can be deleted, I would recommend you separate the check into a method on both the Course class and Department class, as per the best practice of abiding the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by showing the destroy link all the time.. And on clicking the link, an ajax call to delete will be triggered. If the database had the foreign key constraint, we would catch it and show the user it cant be deleted.

So needless for any db query to check constraints...